# LDAP filter: how to get users that are 'after' the MaxPageSize

Tags: filter, directory, ldap

our customer has about 50 000 users in AD and the MaxPage is 1000.
This means that every time we try to run the import it will always take only 1000 users (next time it will take the same 1000 users) from the beginning.

Is there a way to import 'second' page (users from 1001-2000) and others (2001-3000, 3001-4000 etc) by using LDAP filter?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would use the [Simple Paged Results Control](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2696)

There is an example at [LDAPWIKI.COM](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Simple%20Paged%20Results%20Control)